# Insert image to DOM resized to 50% of its width/height

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to insert an image to a page with JavaScript with 50% of its width and 50% of its height.

I do this:

```
someElement.html('<img src="/path/to/img.jpg" alt="" class="sImg" />');
```

The sImg class is defined in stylesheet like this:

```
.sImg{
    border: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Yet the image appears fullsize.

I have also checked via Firebug and the image has width and height both at 50%.

Comment: 50% of what right now it will take 50% of its parent element

Comment: It's unlikely, but it's not overflowing, is it? if the css 'overflow' property is set to 'visible', it'll still show the whole image regardless of what size you make the img tag.

Comment: You sure there's nothing more to the case? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/3qFRn/)

Comment: Probably the Image HTML element does not respect CSS width and hight attributes. Did you try setting Width and Height at the HTML element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS you've got means that the width and height should be computed as half the size of the **parent container**, not the image itself.

What you can do is something like this:  create an Image object and give it an "onload" handler.  The handler can get reliable size information (because the image will have been loaded), and can then add the image element with the proper size.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  $(someElement).empty().append($('<img/>', {
    src: img.src,
    alt: '',
    'class': 'sImg',
    css: { width: Math.floor(img.width / 2) + 'px', height: Math.floor(img.height / 2) + 'px', display: 'inline-block' } // display should be set as you need it
  });
};
img.src = yourUrl;
```

*edit* — the eerily knowledgeable Šime Vidas points out that setting the "width" **or** "height" attribute should make the right thing happen, with the size being reduced appropriately to maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: [Images adjust their other dimension automatically](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/q4UzN/1/) - therefore, you only need to set the width *or* height, not both.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - you just know **so** much stuff :-)

Comment: Nothing special. Just little bits of knowledge I picked up from hanging out on SO.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you're setting a width and height, you should also include `display: block;` since inline elements don't generally enjoy being given a set height.

But more importantly, when you express a width (or height) as a percentage, that's a percentage **of the parent element**, so if the parent is 1000px wide, the image will be 500px wide (regardless of what size the actual image file is).

If you're using JavaScript to determine the current image size and change it, just express the new size in `px` instead of `%`.

Comment: IMG elements are *replaced* inline elements, and the `width` property applies normally to such elements. It's the *non-replaced* inline elements for which the `width` property doesn't apply to.

Answer (score 2):

Does the parent container have a height/width? it maybe that the browser does not know what 50% of x is and what 50% of y is. but if it knew what x and y were then it could apply it. Try

```
var myWidth = $('.sImg').width(),
myHeight = $('.sImg').height();

myWidth = myWidth / 2;
myHeight = myHeight / 2;

$('.sImg').attr('width', myWidth + 'px').attr('height', myHeight + 'px');
```

http://api.jquery.com/width/

http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Getting the image size cannot be done reliably until the image is loaded. At that point, it'll be too big already.

Comment: Oh yes I see... I didn't think of it like that. I dont normally resize images in this way as the browser can really mess the quality up. I'd rather resize it using a proper img editor and then use that version

Comment: yes I agree - it's also sort-of wasteful to download 4 times as many pixels as you need :-)